# Apache Felix @Reference annotation problems

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, apache-felix, sling

I am currently working on a Sling servlet which makes use of the OSGi framework via Apache Felix. From what I understand, if you want to get and use another service, you have two options:
1. Write a service listener which makes sure the service you want is registered before acquiring and using your service.
2. Use the `@Reference` annotation from Apache Felix to acquire the service.

I want to do option 2, as option 1 requires lots of code that I don't need to write.

So, here's how I've done it. Just a disclaimer: what follows are snippets of my code and do not constitute my entire project. Do not expect to be able to compile this or anything. I have included what I believe to be the relevant parts.

First, I have my sling servlet:

```
package mypackage;
import /*necessary imports*/

@Component( name = "My Sling Servlet", immediate = false, metatype = true)
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = "/bin/mytest"),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "GET")
})

@Service(Servlet.class)
public class MyServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
    @Reference
    private MyService service;

    // Do stuff with service
}
```

As far as I understand, the `@Component` annotation lets OSGi know that this class file defines a component. The `@Properties` annotation defines some of the essential properties of the component (in this case, it's important for us to now that we could run this servlet by going to `[hostname]/bin/mytest`). The `@Service` annotation lets OSGi know that this class is a service (in particular, one which implements the Servlet class), and also registers the service. Finally, the `@Reference` annotation tells OSGi that the field we are about to declare is an already registered OSGi service in this bundle, and that we should just grab it.

Now, here's another relevant file, which defines the service MyService:

```
package mypackage;
import /*necessary imports*/

@Component(name="MyService", immediate=false,metatype=true)

@Service(value = MyServiceInterface.class)
public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface {
    // Implementation of MyServiceInterface
}
```

Here, we have declared that MyService is an OSGi component using the `@Component` annotation. The important note here is that we used the `@Service` annotation, which apparently accomplishes an essential task: **the `@Service` annotation REGISTERS the service.**

Please just assume that there is a file MyServiceInterface.java that looks something like this:

```
package mypackage;
import /*necessary imports*/

public interface MyServiceInterface {
    //stuff
}
```

With all of those preliminaries out of the way, here's my issue. When I run my servlet by visiting `[hostname]/bin/mytest` in a web browser, I get a 404 page not found error. This indicates that my browser cannot find the servlet.

You may now be asking yourself why I think this is somehow related to the `@Reference` annotation. Well, I think it is somehow responsible because when I comment it out and acquire the service the old fashioned way (i.e. method 1 above), the servlet runs without any problems.

Another potentially relevant piece of information is that I'm using Maven to build this project. I'm happy to provide the relevant pom.xml files if you think they would contain useful information.

Please help me figure out why my servlet cannot be found when I use the `@Reference` annotation! If you need me to provide more information before helping me then I'm happy to do so. Please indicate in the comments if I have not provided enough information.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Have you attached a debugger? Have you implemented the #doGet method and is being reached?

Comment: Yes, I have a debugger and I have overridden the `doGet` method. The `doGet` method is not reached when the `@Reference` annotation is present. However, it is definitely reached when I remove the annotation.

Comment: What happens if you set immediate to true?

Comment: When you install your bundle are there any errors in the log?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I always do is check to see if my bundles and servlets are active in the Apache Felix console at http://localhost:8080/system/console/bundles and http://localhost:8080/system/console/components. Do you have any missing dependencies that's preventing your bundle or component from becoming active?

Based on your question, my first guess is that you might not be using the [Apache Felix Maven SCR Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html). As you stated, you don't want to manually create ServiceListeners (your stated option 1) but would rather use Declarative Services (your stated option 2) and to do that you need the SCR plugin. Annotations such as `@Reference` are not runtime, they are used by the SCR plugin to generate the code and metadata needed for your service to work in the OSGi environment with Declarative Services. The documentation link provided above gives a detailed account of the plugin's function. Just add the plugin to your `pom.xml` file as demonstrated in the documentation:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>scr</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

See [Using the Apache Felix Maven SCR Plugin to generate Declarative Services and Metatype Service descriptors during a Maven Build](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin-use.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response! These are both good things to check. As for the component, I have already verified that it is active via the console. As for the SCR plugin, I've made sure it's included in my `pom.xml` file. Nevertheless, I'm still having the same issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your servlet works without the reference and it stops working as soon as you add the reference, then the reference itself should be the problem.

The most obvious solution would be that the reference is not accessible (for whatever reason, maybe the service interface class is not exported but it is in another bundle?) so it has status "unsatisfied". In that case the servlet would not start.

Did you really check your servlet in /system/console/components or did you only check the corresponding component?

BTW your servlet does not need all those annotations. Simply use
@SlingServlet(paths = { "/bin/mytest" }, metatype = false, generateService = true)
You can remove the @Component and @Service then.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to know what causes this:
sometimes you use more than one dependency for one object (specially in large-scale projects) which causes IDE won't be able to recognize which one do you mean.

in my case:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
        <version>${onos.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onos-providers-openflow-meter</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

both point to a same object so using @Reference annotation causes a problem that IDE isn't able to inject that object.
and the text of error might be like this:

```
Annotation @reference is disallowed for this location.
```

now you know the problem, how to fix that:
don't use dependencies more than your project need.
in the above example deleting the second dependency solves the problem.

the other way is to set which dependency exactly do you mean:
as you know there are multiple ways to use @Reference annotations in OSGi annotations.
instead of using:

```
@Reference
MyService myService;
```

use this:

```
private MyService myService;
@Reference
public void bindMyService(MyService myService) {
     this.myService = myService;
}
public void unbindMyService(MyService myService) {
     this.myService = myService;
}
```

second option solves the problem.